# App Engine PHP Runtime with Source Code from Bitbucket

Tags: php, git, google-app-engine, bitbucket

We want to use Google App Engine PHP Runtime with the new Source Code from Bitbucket for continuous integration. Than we want to use Cloud SQL.

We are not able to deploy or run the project.

So far we type gcloud init and it copied all the files from source code to the default folder.

After that going to project-id.appspot.com bring this up after beeing redirected to https://project-id.appspot.com

> Cloud Datastore service
>
> Google Cloud Datastore is a fully managed, schemaless database for
>   storing non-relational data.
>
> If you were not expecting to see this page, check out the activation
>   guide for more information.

Is it possible to achieve this sort of integration with App Engine PHP Runtime - Cloud SQL and Source Code that is cloned from Bitbucket?

The source code push to deploy works in the sense when we push an update to the master branch in Bicbucket it automatically gets updated in the Google Cloud Source Code.

app.yaml is the core yaml file.

```
application: project-id
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

Update : the app engine app is live at https://dentem-dot-dentem-network.appspot.com/

app.yaml Corrections for those who will need them!

```
application: project-id
version: 1
runtime: php55 //Has to be php55 in order to work
module: my-module //You have to declare a module in order for the app to run
api_version: 1
```

Edit : To achieve Continuous integration with Google App Engine the documentation was bad. Now everything is fine.

Comment: Your application's project-id should be same as in the dev console. So you need to edit your `app.yaml` file, and set `application:` to be the project ID from https://console.developers.google.com/

Comment: @JeffreyGodwyll we know that much in fact the real yaml is different by much now!

We managed to get this online at https://dentem-dot-dentem-network.appspot.com/ 

Looking for the best way to achieve CI for this project.

Comment: The weird thing is that the the url is not dentem-network.appspot.com but dentem-dot-dentem-network.appspot.com witch we don't know how it got here. Other than that google documentation for PHP Runtime environment is a little outdated. it need a module: in the yaml file and it has to be runtime : php55 or you have to manually white list php54

Comment: In the cloud console you should ensure you've set a default version of the app

Comment: @JeffreyGodwyll :) The new console did not allow that up until the project was created and pushed.

Comment: :) I'm combining both comments into an answer then

Comment: @JeffreyGodwyll That is not totally what we need. We need to push to Bitbucket and the source will be copied to source code (Beta) which has to be deplyed to the project page.

Comment: Usually, the reason you see the Datstore message at the default URL is when you deployed the Datatore API *BEFORE* deploying at least one version of your app. App Engine gets confused about the default version and runs the hidden Datastore container as your default version. It can be fixed by playing with the default version (I.e. Switching back and forth from another deployed version).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using gcloud on Travis CI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492230/using-gcloud-on-travis-ci)

Answer (score 0):

The guys at Google updated their documentation. To avhieve what we wanted you can now use this Jenkins Push-to-Deploy.

[Documentation here 
https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy](https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy)